# Check that a method is not invoked

Tags: java, jmockit

I want to check that a method is not run and tried to do it with an Expectation setting `times = 0;`, however I don't get the expected behaviour.

For example, the following test passes, although the `Session#stop` method is called, and the expectation has a `times = 0;` condition:

```
public static class Session {
    public void stop() {}
}

public static class Whatever {
    Session s = new Session();
    public synchronized void method() {
        s.stop();
    }
}

@Test
public void testWhatever () throws Exception {
    new Expectations(Session.class) {
        @Mocked Session s;
        { s.stop(); times = 0; } //Session#stop must not be called
    };
    final Whatever w = new Whatever();
    w.method(); // this method calls Session#stop => the test should fail...
                // ... but it passes
}
```

Note: If I replace the code with `{ s.stop(); times = 1; }`, the test passes too: I must be missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason of the unexpected mocking behavior is that you inadvertently used *partial* mocking on an strictly mocked type. In this case, recording an expectation with `times = <n>` means that the first `n` matching invocations will be mocked, and after that any additional invocations will execute the original "unmocked" method. With *regular* mocking instead, you would get the expected behavior (ie, an `UnexpectedInvocation` getting thrown after `n` invocations).

The proper way to write the test is:

```
public static class Session { public void stop() {} }
public static class Whatever {
    Session s = new Session();
    public synchronized void method() { s.stop(); }
}

@Test
public void testWhatever ()
{
    new Expectations() {
        @Mocked Session s;
        { s.stop(); times = 0; }
    };

    final Whatever w = new Whatever();
    w.method();
}
```

Alternatively, it can also be written with a *verification* block instead, which is usually better for situations like these:

```
@Test
public void testWhatever (@Mocked final Session s)
{
    final Whatever w = new Whatever();
    w.method();

    new Verifications() {{ s.stop(); times = 0; }};
}
```

Comment: The first code block in your answer still does not works. Expectation of times = 0 or 1 both passed !!.  Using `StrictExpectations` seems to solve this properly.

Answer (score 3):

Related to this I had trouble with JMockit, times = 0 and the @Tested annotation.

With the @Tested annotation you still have a 'real' class, so when registering an Expectation or a Verification (even with times = 0) on this real class, JMockit tries to execute the method. Solution is to partially mock the class in the Expectations:

```
@Tested
Session s;

new Expectations(Session.class) {{ 
   s.stop(); times = 0; } //Session#stop must not be called
};
```

This is the only way I found to use times=0 on methods from @Tested classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with the `MockUp` class - the test below fails as expected - **I would still like to understand why the original approach was not working**.

```
@Test
public void testWhatever () throws Exception {
    new MockUp<Session>() {
        @Mock
        public void stop() {
            fail("stop should not have been called");
        }
    };
    final Whatever w = new Whatever();
    w.method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maxTimes instead, you also can reference stop() in a static way:

```
@Test
public void test(@Mocked Session mockSession){

  final Whatever w = new Whatever();
  w.method();

  new Verifications(){
    {
       Session.stop();
       maxTimes = 0;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From memory, something like

```
verify( s  , times(0) ).stop();
```

will work. Trouble is, the `Session` in `Whatever` isn't your `@Mock`'ed one, but another object, so insert a

```
w.s = s;
```

just before `w.method()`.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with jmockit, but I don't see any `verify` method and I believe mocking is based on type only, so `w.s = s` is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, that's a Mockito feature, I missed the jmockit tag - my bad. Still, I think my argument is valid, how should the mocked `Session` object have anything to do with the `Whatever` session object (at least that's how it would work with Mockito)?

Comment: In jmockit, you mock a type, not an instance. So in my example, all Session instances should be mocked. Unless I misunderstood something of course ;-) Thanks anyway.